# MongoDriver.sndrcv(query): comms error (Can't reconnect)

Tags: opa

I have a strange error suddenly when running my Opa script after it successfully compiled:

```
Jeroens-MacBook-Pro:CollabTextEditor jeroen$ ./CollabTextEditor.exe 
Http serving on http://Jeroens-MacBook-Pro.local:8080
DbGen/Mongo Looking for MongoDB in directory '/Users/jeroen/.opa/mongo'
DbGen/Mongo MongoDB seems launched (pid:438)
MongoDriver.sndrcv(query): comms error (Can't reconnect)
File "lib/stdlib/apis/mongo/log.opa", line 73, characters 5-16, (73:5-73:16 | 2930-2941)
fail: -1
```

A quick Google search didn't give me any answer :s So I tried to find the file log.opa which is mentioned in the errormessage but `sudo find / -name "log.opa"` returned nothing. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found my own answer after trying for almost 2 days.

The problem lay in MongoDb. In some sort of freakish way, MongoDb had made the data corrupt which lead to the error in my question. What I have done to solve it, was start MongoDb by myself. Firstly, I killed any process related to MongoDb and manually started MongoD:

```
./mongod --dbpath /Users/jeroen/.opa/mongo/data/ -v
```

I had to start Opa without itself starting up a MongoDb instance via:

```
./CollabTextEditor.exe --db-remote localhost:27017
```

(CollabTextEditor.exe is the result of compiling my Opa code). I then browsed to localhost:8080 (where Opa was running) which resulted in the following output in MongoD:

```
Jeroens-MacBook-Pro:bin jeroen$ ./mongod --dbpath /Users/jeroen/.opa/mongo/data/ -v
Fri Jan  4 10:03:05 BackgroundJob starting: DataFileSync
Fri Jan  4 10:03:05 versionCmpTest passed
Fri Jan  4 10:03:05 versionArrayTest passed
Fri Jan  4 10:03:05 shardObjTest passed
Fri Jan  4 10:03:05 shardKeyTest passed
Fri Jan  4 10:03:05 isInRangeTest passed
Fri Jan  4 10:03:05 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=15654 port=27017 dbpath=/Users/jeroen/.opa/mongo/data/ 64-bit host=Jeroens-MacBook-Pro.local
Fri Jan  4 10:03:05 [initandlisten] db version v2.0.2, pdfile version 4.5
Fri Jan  4 10:03:05 [initandlisten] git version: 514b122d308928517f5841888ceaa4246a7f18e3
Fri Jan  4 10:03:05 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin erh2.10gen.cc 9.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 9.6.0: Mon Nov 24 17:37:00 PST 2008; root:xnu-1228.9.59~1/RELEASE_I386 i386 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_40
Fri Jan  4 10:03:05 [initandlisten] options: { dbpath: "/Users/jeroen/.opa/mongo/data/", verbose: true }
Fri Jan  4 10:03:05 [initandlisten] journal dir=/Users/jeroen/.opa/mongo/data/journal
Fri Jan  4 10:03:05 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Fri Jan  4 10:03:05 [initandlisten] Accessing: local for the first time
Fri Jan  4 10:03:05 [initandlisten] query local.system.namespaces reslen:20 0ms
Fri Jan  4 10:03:05 [initandlisten] enter repairDatabases (to check pdfile version #)
Fri Jan  4 10:03:05 [initandlisten]     CollabTextEditor
Fri Jan  4 10:03:05 [initandlisten] Accessing: CollabTextEditor for the first time
Fri Jan  4 10:03:05 [initandlisten] done repairDatabases
Fri Jan  4 10:03:05 BackgroundJob starting: snapshot
Fri Jan  4 10:03:05 BackgroundJob starting: ClientCursorMonitor
Fri Jan  4 10:03:05 BackgroundJob starting: PeriodicTask::Runner
Fri Jan  4 10:03:05 [initandlisten] fd limit hard:9223372036854775807 soft:256 max conn: 204
Fri Jan  4 10:03:05 [websvr] fd limit hard:9223372036854775807 soft:256 max conn: 204
Fri Jan  4 10:03:05 [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on port 28017
Fri Jan  4 10:03:05 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
Fri Jan  4 10:03:46 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:54604 #1
Fri Jan  4 10:03:46 [conn1] Accessing: CollabTextEditor for the first time
Fri Jan  4 10:03:46 [conn1] query CollabTextEditor.user reslen:20 0ms
Fri Jan  4 10:03:46 [conn1] query CollabTextEditor.room nreturned:1 reslen:3379 0ms
Fri Jan  4 10:04:05 [DataFileSync] flushing mmap took 2ms  for 3 files
Fri Jan  4 10:04:05 [PeriodicTask::Runner] task: DBConnectionPool-cleaner took: 0ms
Fri Jan  4 10:04:05 [PeriodicTask::Runner] task: DBConnectionPool-cleaner took: 0ms
Fri Jan  4 10:04:05 [PeriodicTask::Runner] task: WriteBackManager::cleaner took: 0ms
Fri Jan  4 10:04:05 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:30 virt:2594 mapped:80
Fri Jan  4 10:04:32 [conn1] query CollabTextEditor.user idhack:1 reslen:20 0ms
Fri Jan  4 10:04:32 [conn1] update CollabTextEditor.user query: { _id: "test" } update: { $set: { value: { some: { name: "test" } } } } fastmodinsert:1 0ms
Fri Jan  4 10:04:32 [conn1] run command CollabTextEditor.$cmd { getlasterror: 1 }
Fri Jan  4 10:04:32 [conn1] command CollabTextEditor.$cmd command: { getlasterror: 1 } ntoreturn:1 reslen:85 0ms
Fri Jan  4 10:04:32 [conn1] query CollabTextEditor.room nreturned:1 reslen:3379 0ms
Fri Jan  4 10:04:32 [journal] lsn set 55971
Fri Jan  4 10:05:01 [conn1] end connection 127.0.0.1:54604
```

The fact that some queries seemed to return `nreturned:1` (look at the final lines in the output) and some didn't meant that something was probably wrong with my data. This lead to the error in my question.

What I did to actually resolve it, was connect to Mongo separately and to drop the database after a mongod instance was already running:

```
Jeroens-MacBook-Pro:bin jeroen$ ./mongo localhost:27017
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.2
connecting to: localhost:27017/test
> use CollabTextEditor
switched to db CollabTextEditor
> db.dropDatabase()
{ "dropped" : "CollabTextEditor", "ok" : 1 }
> exit
bye
```

After this, the script didn't return any errors anymore. So I can conclude that MongoDB probably crashed (reason unknown) which resulted in corrupt data which caused a snowball effect. Quite the stupid error, if some better error reporting was available in MongoDb and Opa, I probably wouldn't have wasted so much precious time. Hopefully this helps someone else :)